# Difference between KeWaitForSingleObject with 0 timeout and KeReadStateSemaphore

Tags: windows, semaphore, wdk

Is there any difference between `KeWaitForSingleObject` with timeout set to 0 and `KeReadStateSemaphore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very big difference. While `KeReadStateSemaphore` simply returns the state of the semaphore, `KeWaitForSingleObject` with a timeout of 0 will actually process side-effects should the wait be satisfied (i.e. the side-effect is to decrement the signal state). Use the former to poll, and use the latter to try to acquire a semaphore without waiting.

Comment: so if thread-A called KeWaitForSingleObject and hasn't released the semaphore, can thread-B call KeWaitForSingleObject with timeout set to 0 and acquire the semaphore? what effect will the call to KeReleaseSemaphore on thread-A have then?

Comment: @lalli: No, if the first thread hasn't released the semaphore then nothing will happen when the second thread calls KeWaitForSingleObject. When it's released nothing will happen either since no thread is waiting on the semaphore.